# Rotate Back and Forth on Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, image, rotation

Why does my code not work? I want the `".plane"`to rotate back and forth as I scroll.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var sdegree = 0;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (window.pageYOffset > 400) {
                sdegree ++;
                sdegree = sdegree + 3;
                var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
                $(".plane").css({
                    "-moz-transform": srotate,
                    "-webkit-transform" : srotate
                });
            } else {
                sdegree ++;
                sdegree = sdegree - 3;
                var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
                $(".plae").css({
                    "-moz-transform": srotate,
                    "-webkit-transform": srotate
                });
            }
        } 
</script>
```

Comment: you are missing closing parentheses and curly parentheses. it seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/e6yeH/

Comment: can you specify where

Comment: What errors are you getting? (Look in your JavaScript console by right clicking and selecting inspect element, then go to "Console" or "JavaScript Console" or something like that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $.css() won't work because of the syntax. `$('.myDiv').css('background-color', 'red')` is ok, and it becomes `$('.myDiv').css({backgroundColor: 'red'})` when your are using brackets.

**Try this code:**

```
$(function() {
  var sdegree = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    sdegree = sdegree + 4;
    var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
    $(".plane").css({
      transform : srotate
    });
  });
});
```

JSbin: http://jsbin.com/nuqezazu/1/

**My contribution:**

```
$(function() {
  var sdegree = 0;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    sdegree = ( st > lastScrollTop ) ? sdegree + 4 : sdegree - 4;
    var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
    $(".plane").css({transform : srotate});
   lastScrollTop = st;
  });
});
```

JSbin: http://jsbin.com/nuqezazu/2/

Comment: Perfect! But how do I add the if statement to that without messing up the close brackets?

Comment: You if statement just gonna change ``sdegree`` so you can do:
``sdegree = ( window.pageYOffset > 400 ) ? sdegree + 4 : sdegree - 4;``

Comment: __ EDIT: I've added my contribution to my post, check it out, it could help you.

Comment: Cache your `$('.plane')` element. There's really no need to ask jQuery to go all over the DOM to get your selector on every single scroll event

Answer (score 1):

Something simple and accurate*?

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yuneg/2/edit)**

```
$(function() {

  var $plane = $('.plane'); // Cache your elements!
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      $plane.css({transform: 'rotate('+ window.pageYOffset%360 +'deg)'}); 
  });

});
```

No need to set all the `vendor-specific` properties as jQuery does that for you out of the box.
Than simply use the *Reminder Operator %* to loop you 360 degrees :)

**You'd like to control the rotation speed?** Nothing that trivial like: **[demo](http://jsbin.com/yuneg/3/edit)**

```
  var deg = (window.pageYOffset/10)%360;
  $plane.css({transform: 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)'});
```

- I said accurate cause your element will always return at the very initial state when the scroll is at 0.

Comment: That makes a great ``wind vane`` :3 !

Comment: That's the instrument used for showing the direction of the wind. http://j.mp/1gJg0Nf French have great ones on top of some buildings. ;-)

Comment: @AllanStepps yes yes I have already googled :) was missign that word in my dictionary :) hahaha